# How to get a value out of tensor?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

My python function is returning `tensor([102],cuda::0)` like structure. How do I obtain the first value from this?

Answer (score 0):

Found this on [pytorch discussion forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/get-value-out-of-torch-cuda-float-tensor/2539):

```
a.data.cpu().numpy()[0]
```

where `a` is the tensor.